# Create Postgres View involving multiple tables

Tags: postgresql

Postgres Version 9.4

I already have this query involving two tables namely, `surigao_stats_2yr` and `evidensapp_surigaobldg`.

```
SELECT
    province,
    municipali AS municipality,
    brgy_locat AS barangay,
    total_bldg,
    (total_bldg - count(id)) as total_not_affected,
    count(id) AS total_affected,
    count(id) FILTER (WHERE gridcode = 1) AS low,
    count(id) FILTER (WHERE gridcode = 2) AS medium,
    count(id) FILTER (WHERE gridcode = 3) AS high
FROM    (
    SELECT
    pss.province,ps.id, ps.brgy_locat, ps.municipali,
    gridcode, count(pss.id) as total_bldg
    FROM  surigao_stats_2yr ps
INNER JOIN
    evidensapp_surigaobldg pss
    ON ps.brgy_locat = pss.brgy_locat
    AND ps.municipali = pss.municipali
GROUP BY 1, 2,3, 4, 5
    )
AS ps_fh GROUP BY 1,2,3, 4
ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 ASC
```

The result of the query above is this:
[image]

I wanted to have a view involving another two tables with the same result `where` it can be filtered by `municipality` and `barangay` and sum the `total_bldg`, `total_not_affected`, `total_affected`, `low`, `medium` and `high` if the `municipality` and `barangay` is the same.

So far, I have tried this:

```
CREATE VIEW surigao_del_norte_2yr_affected AS
SELECT 
    province,
    municipality,
    barangay,
    SUM(total_bldg) as tot_bldg,
    SUM(total_not_affected) as tot_not_affect,
    SUM(total_affected) as tot_affect,
    SUM(low) as lo,
    SUM(medium) as med,
    SUM(high)as hi
FROM(
    WITH surigao AS(
        SELECT
            province,
            municipali AS municipality,
            brgy_locat AS barangay,
            total_bldg,
            (total_bldg - count(id)) as total_not_affected,
            count(id) AS total_affected,
            count(id) FILTER (WHERE gridcode = 1) AS low,
            count(id) FILTER (WHERE gridcode = 2) AS medium,
            count(id) FILTER (WHERE gridcode = 3) AS high
        FROM    (
            SELECT
            pss.province,ps.id, ps.brgy_locat, ps.municipali,
            gridcode, count(pss.id) as total_bldg
            FROM  surigao_stats_2yr ps
        INNER JOIN
            evidensapp_surigaobldg pss
            ON ps.brgy_locat = pss.brgy_locat
            AND ps.municipali = pss.municipali
        GROUP BY 1, 2,3, 4, 5
            )
        AS ps_fh GROUP BY 1,2,3, 4
        ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 ASC
    
    ), magallanes AS(
        SELECT
            province,
            municipali AS municipality,
            brgy_locat AS barangay,
            total_bldg,
            (total_bldg - count(id)) as total_not_affected,
            count(id) AS total_affected,
            count(id) FILTER (WHERE gridcode = 1) AS low,
            count(id) FILTER (WHERE gridcode = 2) AS medium,
            count(id) FILTER (WHERE gridcode = 3) AS high
        FROM    (
            SELECT
            pss.province,ps.id, ps.brgy_locat, ps.municipali,
            gridcode, count(pss.id) as total_bldg
            FROM  magallanes_stats_2yr ps
        INNER JOIN
            evidensapp_magallanesbldg pss
            ON ps.brgy_locat = pss.brgy_locat
            AND ps.municipali = pss.municipali
        GROUP BY 1, 2,3, 4, 5
            )
        AS ps_fh GROUP BY 1,2,3, 4
        ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 ASC
    ), mainit AS(
        SELECT
            province,
            municipali AS municipality,
            brgy_locat AS barangay,
            total_bldg,
            (total_bldg - count(id)) as total_not_affected,
            count(id) AS total_affected,
            count(id) FILTER (WHERE gridcode = 1) AS low,
            count(id) FILTER (WHERE gridcode = 2) AS medium,
            count(id) FILTER (WHERE gridcode = 3) AS high
        FROM    (
            SELECT
            pss.province,ps.id, ps.brgy_locat, ps.municipali,
            gridcode, count(pss.id) as total_bldg
            FROM  mainit_tubay_stats_2yr ps
        INNER JOIN
            evidensapp_mainittubaybldg pss
            ON ps.brgy_locat = pss.brgy_locat
            AND ps.municipali = pss.municipali
            WHERE province='Surigao del Norte'
        GROUP BY 1, 2,3, 4, 5
            )
        AS ps_fh GROUP BY 1,2,3, 4
        ORDER BY 1 ASC, 2 ASC
    )
    TABLE surigao 
    UNION ALL
    TABLE magallanes
    UNION ALL
    TABLE mainit
) surigao_2yr
--WHERE municipality ='Placer' 
--AND barangay = 'Santa Cruz'
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 2



SELECT *FROM surigao_del_norte_2yr_affected WHERE municipality ='Placer' AND barangay = 'Santa Cruz'
```

The performance is quite slow and I want to know if the values mentioned above is added with the query I had.

Thanks.

Comment: A non materialized view will only perform as well as its underlying query.  Your question then is really about how to make the second query faster.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Anyway, is my query correct? does it sum total_bldg, total_not_affected, total_affected, low, medium and high if the municipality and barangay is the same?